# Unable to connect to mongodb with compass, but can via mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb

I'm really confused. I'm able to connect to mongodb with the shell but not compass via connection string or manually typing fields (the option at top right).

Here's the shell connection:

```
mongo --username myAdminUser --password password123 --authenticationDatabase myAdminDatabase --host localhost --port 27020
```

I've tried a few connection strings /?authSource=myAdminDatavase, /myAdminDatabase, I've even tried them together...
I'd love a single connection string that I can use in compass.

Here is the connection string the shell outputs once it connects:

```
mongodb://localhost:27020/isMaster?authSource=myAuthDatabase&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
```

I tried this with credentials also.

My environment is a little odd, but cannot be changed. I'm in a virtual machine, with a local k8s cluster hosting the mongo instance in a pod. These connections are all forwarded through to my host, which I use to connect to mongo from the shell and it works successfully.

The shell is fine, but sometimes just tweaking a document slightly via compass is convenient and a more pleasant experience.

If anyone could shed any light on this I'd massively appreciate it!

Comment: Here is some info about how the connection string is formed: [Connection String URI Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/connection-string/index.html).

Comment: I've been through all of it aha :P ensuring I'm ssl, not tls and whatnot. I'm definitely on basic plain credentials too, obviously cause of the shell connection lol. I'm stumped honestly.

Comment: What versions of MongoDB and Compass? Here is info about [connecting in Compass using individual fields of the URI](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/connect#open-the-individual-connection-fields-view).

Comment: Db version is 4.2.7 and compass is 1.22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve it, SSL only supports single way tunneling, so I had to turn SSL off in my mongo instance and disable it on my connection string, this worked fine. Hopefully this helps anyone else working remotely and struggling.

Comment: I've had this same problem now! View -> Reload, using the same connection string worked for me